# Android Logout of App

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using a contentprovider, and 3 variables on the shared prefs, I'm wondering how to best 'log the user out'..

I would expect it to truncate the db, and clear/delete shared prefs variables..

Currently I am clearing the shared prefs, and deleting the database, then taking the user back to the login screen.

```
SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();

// wipe user specific data
editor.remove("authenticated_user_id");
editor.remove("api_key");
editor.remove("last_sync_updates");

editor.commit();

// TODO possibly truncate rather than delete
// the apps database
getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase(
        DatabaseConstants.DATABASE_NAME);

// send the user to the login screen
Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
startActivity(logoutIntent);
```

But it doesn't seem to clear the database, and I get database access errors randomly on the first transaction after logging out..

How is this typically done?

Comment: Are you closing your `SQLiteOpenHelper` before you delete the database and then re-creating one immediately after in case the user wishes to log back in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**Google I/O 2012**](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/#git/android) application does something similar so you might want to check that out. When the user [**logs out**](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/HomeActivity.java#361), the following [**call**](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/AccountUtils.java#148) to the `ContentResolver` is made:

```
getContentResolver().delete(ScheduleContract.BASE_CONTENT_URI, null, null);
```

This calls the `ScheduleProvider`'s delete method:

```
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    if (uri == ScheduleContract.BASE_CONTENT_URI) {
        // Handle whole database deletes (e.g. when signing out)
        deleteDatabase();
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null, false);
        return 1;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

where `deleteDatabase()` is the following private helper method:

```
private void deleteDatabase() {
    mOpenHelper.close();
    Context context = getContext();
    context.deleteDatabase(ScheduleContract.DATABASE_NAME);
    mOpenHelper = new ScheduleDatabase(context);
}
```

You can see the exact sequence of events that occurs beginning in [**`ScheduleProvider.java`**](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/provider/ScheduleProvider.java).

Comment: So, I have more than 1 CONTENT_URI, so I just have to call this for each of them?

Comment: And, presumably this only does the data deletion..? Do I need to be doing something like: http://www.hrupin.com/2011/11/how-to-clear-user-data-in-your-android-application-programmatically

Comment: It doesn't matter which uri you use... you could create a new one called `CONTENT_URI_SIGN_OUT` or something instead. Just make sure you don't accidentally call `delete` on it or else you'll unknowingly delete all of the user's information.

Comment: And I don't think you need to do that... I would think that `Context#deleteDatabase(String name)` would delete all of that internally stored information for you.